# Is RTL - support android for web base application

Tags: android, iphone, html, css, web

I am developing mobile web application for Arabic Localization, we had done lots of page on that language, but I had a one query regarding select option drop down, which is not perfectly work.

Our requirement is to show that drop down arrow on left side and text should be on right side.

I face issue for specific device on native browser like, iPhone, Samsung galaxy S-3

Can anybody help me for the same?

Answer (score 0):

I think your only option is to use something like jquery-UI.
I need this to be done with Farsi language and I've had no luck with it either...